# React-Select : Options appear blank

Tags: reactjs, react-select

When I select the options in `react-select`, Options appear blank as such the font are in white font over the white back-ground. I have attached the picture for the reference
Note: I have not included `className` attribute in the code.

[image: Attached the Image for the reference]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of your code ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you use any components inside? When you use <Select .... components={....}/> may be a problem. Or try to use GetOptionLabel/GetOptionValue.
In case it's okey, please share your code here.

Comment: did you figure out what was causing this problem?